# How to get datarow array refering to datatable 's field value with linq

Tags: c#, linq

I want to use linq to get datarow array from a datatable which its string type ColumnA  is not null or depending on its length >0 , so  I can get the row index with Indexof() method to deal with something else.

```
ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC
A0       B0       C0
Null     B1       C1
A2       B2       C2
Null     B3       C3
```

My Linq Statment:

```
DataRow[] rows =  myDataTable.Select("ColumnA is not null").Where(row=>row.Field<string>("ColumnA").Length>0);
```

somebody who can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `AsEnumerable`, You will have to add `System.Data.DatasetExtensions` reference and 
import `System.Data` to convert the datatable to as enumerable:

To get **INDEX:**

```
int desiredIndex =
            dt.AsEnumerable().ToList().
            FindIndex(r => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(r.Field<string>("ColumnA")) &&
            r.Field<string>("ColumnA").Length > 0);
```

To get **Matched rows list:**

```
  List<DataRow> RowFilter = 
            dt2.AsEnumerable().ToList().Where
            (r => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(r.Field<string>("ColumnA")) &&
            r.Field<string>("ColumnA").Length > 0).ToList();
```

To get **Matched rows array:**

```
  DataRow[] drArray = dt2.AsEnumerable().ToList().Where
       (r => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(r.Field<string>("ColumnA")) &&
       r.Field<string>("ColumnA").Length > 3).ToArray();
```

Comment: Hi Carlos,Actually,I wanna get a DataRow Array which will match the rules(columnA's value is not null),Is desiredIndex a index of the first datarow which matchs rules?I want all matched rowindexs

Comment: Updated ;) here you have